# Translate string to complex OWL axiom

Tags: java, parsing, owl, owl-api

I am trying to parse strings back to OWL Axioms using the OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser based on [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/owlapi/mailman/message/24109072/) example. This works fine for simple axioms, e.g. ObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom. For the following axiom (with *prefix:* being the abbreviation of the URL for clarity here)

```
EquivalentClasses(<prefix:LeucocytesRestricted> ObjectIntersectionOf(<prefix:Leucocytes> DataSomeValuesFrom(<prefix:hasLeucocytesValue> DataRangeRestriction(xsd:double facetRestriction(minInclusive \"20.0\"^^xsd:double)))) )
```

I receive the following exception

```
org.coode.owlapi.functionalparser.ParseException: Encountered "" at line 1, column 260.
Was expecting one of:

    at org.coode.owlapi.functionalparser.OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.generateParseException(OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.java:5335)
    at org.coode.owlapi.functionalparser.OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.jj_consume_token(OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.java:5194)
    at org.coode.owlapi.functionalparser.OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.DataRange(OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.java:761)
    at org.coode.owlapi.functionalparser.OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.DataSomeValuesFrom(OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.java:531)
    at org.coode.owlapi.functionalparser.OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.ClassExpression(OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.java:310)
    at org.coode.owlapi.functionalparser.OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.ClassExpressionSet(OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.java:339)
    at org.coode.owlapi.functionalparser.OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.ObjectIntersectionOf(OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.java:383)
    at org.coode.owlapi.functionalparser.OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.ClassExpression(OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.java:290)
    at org.coode.owlapi.functionalparser.OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.ClassExpressionSet(OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.java:339)
    at org.coode.owlapi.functionalparser.OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.EquivalentClasses(OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.java:932)
    at org.coode.owlapi.functionalparser.OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.ClassAxiom(OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.java:901)
    at org.coode.owlapi.functionalparser.OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.Axiom(OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser.java:867)
    at be.ugent.ontal.ontology.ConflictDetector.stringToAxiom(ConflictDetector.java:125)
    at be.ugent.ontal.ontology.ConflictDetector.addClassAxiom(ConflictDetector.java:74)
    at be.ugent.ontal.facade.command.AddClassAxiomCommand.execute(AddClassAxiomCommand.java:27)
    at be.ugent.ontal.facade.Invoker.storeAndExecute(Invoker.java:13)
    at be.ugent.ontal.facade.MyWebSocket.onText(MyWebSocket.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.annotated.CallableMethod.call(CallableMethod.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.annotated.OptionalSessionCallableMethod.call(OptionalSessionCallableMethod.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyAnnotatedEventDriver.onTextMessage(JettyAnnotatedEventDriver.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.message.SimpleTextMessage.messageComplete(SimpleTextMessage.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.AbstractEventDriver.appendMessage(AbstractEventDriver.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyAnnotatedEventDriver.onTextFrame(JettyAnnotatedEventDriver.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.AbstractEventDriver.incomingFrame(AbstractEventDriver.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession.incomingFrame(WebSocketSession.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.ExtensionStack.incomingFrame(ExtensionStack.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.notifyFrame(Parser.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.parse(Parser.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.readParse(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have also tried the parser.EquivalentClasses(), but this doesn't work either. Is their any way to parse such a complex expression? The ultimate goal is to have an OWLEquivalentClassesAxiom object respresenting this string.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

This is the code I am currently using

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(axiom.getBytes());

OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser parser = new OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser(in);
parser.setUp(ontology, new OWLOntologyLoaderConfiguration());

try {
    System.out.println(axiom);
    output.add(parser.Axiom());
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The example you refer to is from 2009, so it was probably using OWLAPI for OWL 1. Which version are you using, and can you post the code you are using?

Comment: I have added the code as edit. I am currently working with owlapi 3.4.4.

Comment: The input string you're showing is 226 characters long, and the error is reported at column 260 - I'm guessing the change depends on shortening the IRIs for posting here. As pointed out in the answer, the code seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am suspecting that there is a syntax error in your input stream. I cooked a random example and it seems to be working:

```
    String axiom="EquivalentClasses(:TestPizza ObjectIntersectionOf(DataMinCardinality(20 :hasToppingValue xsd:double) :Pizza))";
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(axiom.getBytes());

    OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser parser;
    parser = new OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser(in);
    parser.setUp(localOntology,new OWLOntologyLoaderConfiguration());
    DefaultPrefixManager nsm=new DefaultPrefixManager("http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#");
    parser.setPrefixes(nsm);
     try {
        OWLClassAxiom temp=parser.EquivalentClasses();
        System.out.println(axiom);
        System.out.println(temp);
    } catch ( ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: For the input I am using the functional syntax as [here](http://ontogenesis.knowledgeblog.org/88?kblog-transclude=2), but I still got an exception. The input is  `EquivalentClasses(<http://www.uzalerting.intec.ugent.be/leucocytes#LeucocytesRestricted> ObjectIntersectionOf(<http://www.uzalerting.intec.ugent.be/leucocytes#Leucocytes> DataSomeValuesFrom(<http://www.uzalerting.intec.ugent.be/leucocytes#hasLeucocytesValue> DatatypeRestriction(xsd:double xsd:maxExclusive "20"^^xsd:double ))))` and the error `Encountered " "DataSomeValuesFrom" "DataSomeValuesFrom "" at line 1, column 172`

Comment: I think you have a semantic error somewhere. I just wrote this and it works. I think you should separate your prefix:  String axiom="EquivalentClasses(:LeucocytesRestricted "+
    "ObjectIntersectionOf(:Leucocytes "+
        "DataSomeValuesFrom(:hasLeucocytesValue "+ 
        "DatatypeRestriction(xsd:double "+ 
            "xsd:maxExclusive \"20\"^^xsd:double ))))";

Comment: Which version of the owlapi are you using? Because even for the pizza ontology, I get parser exceptions.

Comment: I am using OWL API 4.0.1.

Comment: I am trying to use the same version (4.0.1), but I got the error "The type org.semanticweb.owlapi.functional.parser.OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser is not visible" when I try to import it in my class. So I am trying to figure out what is wrong, because the OWLFunctionalSyntaxParser is not a private class if you look at the sources.

Comment: Are you putting the exact same code? If you edit your question with code that is throwing the exception, I can have a look.

Comment: I have copy-pasted your code, together with the axiom from the second comment. I'm working with Bndtools in OSGi, so I am trying to find out if I am configuring my bundle properties wrong and maybe that could somehow cause the problems.

Comment: I still think if you rewrite your axiom and separate the prefix your problem would be solved. I think this axiom that you have written has an issue and your copy-pasting it is causing all the problems.